Crystal Reports Formula Errors: A String is Required Here, Field Name Not Known, Number Required - No Code Changes Made
We have been using "SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework(32bit)" version 13.0.15.1840 to generate reports using .rpt files along with data present in .XSD files for several years. All of a sudden, on 30th of April 2024, all the machines where this is installed stopped generating reports and started throwing errors related to CR formula such as
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormulaException: A string is required here
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormulaException: This field name is not known
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormulaException: A number, or currency amount is required here.
Please note that we have not made any configuration or code changes to any of the applications involved. Several users reported the same issue on the same day almost in unison. For some users, the reports did start working after they restarted their computers or after they uninstalled and reinstalled the same version of "SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework(32bit)". But for most of us, issue still persists.
Currently we are on "Windows 11 Enterprise 64-bit (10.0, Build 22631)". We also could replicate the issue on a "Windows Server 2022 Standard (10.0.20348 Build 20348)"
Can you please let us know if this has anything to do with OS upgrade or any extrinsic factors?
We tried on multiple machines with different version of windows OS and restarted machines multiple times.
We tried uninstall and reinstall SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework(32bit).
We also tried with SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework(64bit), however there is no change in the behavior.

Does the expression causing the error use a function from a UFL (User Function Library)?
Did the data source or connection method change?
Please share the full details of one of these errors: the expression, the error message, the cursor position specifying which field is causing the problem, the data connection type.
